# PayPal IPN email issues

Tags: paypal-ipn

I've been getting daily emails from PayPal for the last week, telling me that PayPal IPN's are failing to a specific address. I've changed the listening address in the PayPal IPN panel to the one listed on my site for the plugin it communicates with. But the emails still keep coming. Can anyone offer a solution?[screenshot of email here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXZpy.png)

I changed the IPN address listed in PayPal's IPN panel. This made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IPN url configured in the account is only used if no notify_url is specified at transaction time. If all your transactions specify their own notify_url, the URL configured there has no effect.

So, for new transactions, need to change the URL your integration is specifying at checkout time when it creates the payment attempt/redirects the payer over to PayPal.

For previous transactions and subscription payments that specified a different URL at transaction time, there is no way to change nor update that URL. An old one will continue to be used for refunds and future subscription payments.